# Error in publishing Web service

Tags: java, web-services, axis, wsdl2java

I have a WSDL file from which I have created Server Side Code Skeleton. Now after modification of these skeleton Java classes I have deleted the WSDL file from the project folder. Now, I am trying to prepare a web service for these classes. I m using Axis engine and apache tomcat 5.5 for this which is embedded with the eclipse. But when I start this I m getting the following error.

**IWAB0489E Error when deploying Web service to Axis runtime
  axis-admin failed with  {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**

Can any one help. What is this error??

Comment: are you using eclipse and an internal application server instance?

Comment: Is there anything more to the log? I'd expect to see an exception showing the *cause* of the InvocationTargetException.

Comment: No, there is nothing more in the log , Jon.

Comment: @Stuti Why did you delete the WSDL file, and what changes did you make to the skeleton classes?

Comment: @bakoyaro I want to recreate the WSDL file with the code at the time of publishing web service.

Comment: I have encountered similar issues in eclipse before when using the automated generation for the web-service both client and server side. My code was pretty small so I created a new workspace and project and copied my java file to the new project and re-executed the wsdl2java wizard and it worked. It seemed to be some sort of caching issue within the tomcat instance of eclispe. I never found why tho!

Comment: @Carl Thanks.. for suggestion !! I hope it will work. I will check that and will post response.

Comment: Suggestion: Put a breakpoint on java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException and run the server in debug mode... then you can hopefully see the underlying error. Not sure why you're deleting the WSDL, though. Surely there is little point in auto generating it as your skeleton is fixed to this WSDL?

Comment: Seriously, Axis hasn't been updated in over 5 years. For the love of all that is Java, please don't use it. There are plenty of other SOAP options out there that are much, much better. Spring-ws, Apache CXF...Even Axis2 would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before, the solution?, use JAX-WS instead Axis.

Answer (score 0):

I  think you are trying to call some method from the client skeleton which you've generated from the wsdl file. If you are calling any of the methods which are exposed, make sure that the parameters which you are sending are correct.

userExceptions mostly come with sending wrong params

From my experience: 
[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659829/wsdl2java-codegen-eclipse-plugin-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception)

Comment: "Error when deploying Web service", not calling

Answer (score 0):

invocationTargetException occurs when some of the dependency class might be missed in the cass path(build path) of the webservice project(i mean, the webservice might be used some external jars or external projects as a reference,if suppose those are not in the class path(build path), it shows invocationTargetException exception while building webservice).so make sure all the dependency classes/projects must be in the webservice project class path(build path).