# wsdl2java codegen eclipse plugin- java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception

Tags: eclipse-plugin, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I had added the Axis2_Codegen_Wizard_1.3.0,Axis2_Service_Archiver_1.3.0 to eclipse plugin. On clicking finish button, after I go through all the steps which include specifying wsdl file path and output path, I a pop up with following error.

> An error occurred while completing the process
>
> java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception

Any idea ?
Thanks
-Aj

Comment: Here is an update. I used the 'eclipse - console' from my command prompt and the error it shows is
 java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: edu\emory\mathcs\backport\java\util\concurrent\ConcurrentHashMap   

I am using the backport-util-concurrent-3.1-osgi. jar,backport-util-concurrent-3.1. jar in the library. Even then am getting this error. When I searched through the path given above(in the above mentioned jars), the ConcurrentHashMap.class does exist.

No idea why the error is caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem was solved on upgrading to Eclipse IDE 3.6.