# Unable to Access Amazon Web Service using Axis2 client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, amazon-web-services, apache-axis

I am facing a problem while trying to access **Amazon Web Service**  (http://soap.amazon.com/schemas2/AmazonWebServices.wsdl) using **Axis2 version 1.6.0**

In Eclipse Galileo, I am using Axis2 for generating **client stub** for Amazon Web service and there I am getting the following error :

```
Exception occurred during code generation for WSDL  : 
org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Prior to this, I have created a Soap Web Service using Axis2 and generated stub for the same. It worked properly.

But when I tried to generate the client stub for a Soap Web Service generated using **PHP**, I got the same error that I got while accessing Amazon Web Service. 
Does it create any problem when a PHP Soap Service is accessed from Axis2 client for generating client stub in java?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Above WSDL file contains some SOAP encoding elements as follows.

```
              <xsd:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                    <xsd:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="typens:ProductLine[]"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
```

Axis2 does not support for SOAP encoding that is the reason  for above exception.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure why the error is being caused. If nothing works out, please try changing your eclipse IDE.
I had a lot of trouble with 'TargetInvocationException' when I tried generating client stub from the wsdl using WSDL2JAVA Codegen plugin.
[wsdl2java codegen eclipse plugin- java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659829/wsdl2java-codegen-eclipse-plugin-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception)